# Better Way to Show Categories from the Control Panel?

Tags: categories, control-panel

I've looked everywhere for an Accessory that makes the Control Panel Categories look better:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot I'm eventually going to run into a big issue when I get other States and Cities added and it's going to be a heckuva mess!

I'm envisioning a way to "toggle" the children list of categories here. This way I can have my "Businesses" open (since there aren't many children associated here) AND have the City/State category parents clickable to show their children. This will keep this list a LOT shorter and hence easier to use.

Has anyone done this or seen an Accessory that would do this? Like I said I've search everywhere on Devot-EE and Google to no avail.

Thanks again gang!

Answer (score 5):

I made Category Field for that very reason. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-field

Comment: Awesome - didn't know this was available. Cheers!

Comment: Still, if there are large number of categories, the screen can still be very large. If you add the following to override.css, it will make a large category list scrollable `div.cat_group_container {
 height: 150px;
 overflow: scroll;
}`.

Comment: Another nice add-on to bring categories to the Publish tab or another tab is "Categories Field" by Nathan Pitman. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/categories-field